# One output with multiple files

Tags: command-line

I want to have the one output for a lot MP4 files ,this code output everey file in output separately:

```bsh
for i in *.MP4; do
  ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i/%MP4/ass}"
done
```

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the full details of your situation. Together with https://askubuntu.com/q/1210090/507051 I assume you have a directory with a number of `.MP4` files and want to extract one single `.ass` subtitle file from them, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg/11175851

In resume, what you want to do is:

```bsh
$ cat mylist.txt
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'

$ ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

PS:

To create the file listing all your .mp4 inputs, you can use this command inside the directory containing all your files:

(edit: Thank's to dessert for the better command line into the comments)

```bsh
printf "file '%s'\n" *.MP4 > mylist.txt
```

TL;DR:

One bash line solution (thank's to dessert):

```bsh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" *.MP4) -c copy output.mp4
```

If you want to only retrieve all the subtitle, change the extension on the output file:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" *.MP4) -c copy output.ass
```

Comment: Totally agree, I've updated my answer with your command line which is way cleaner.

Comment: Great!​ :) Now you may combine that with process substitution and save the file creation step: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" *.MP4) -c copy output.mp4` – and as OP (I suppose, see comment on Q) doesn’t really want a `.mp4`, but rather just the subtitle `.ass` file, just use this extension for the output file and the oneliner is ready.